# Can't copy outlook directory to Excel, Word etc

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, copy-paste

Essentially I want to copy my outlook directory to Word or Excel. It is an organisations directory but containing the emails and names of peers - however I am lost as to how to move the data to outside of the outlooks browser. You cannot select the text by dragging the mouse over it and I have tried some Python which also ended up not working.

[image: screenshot of directory]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

File:  Open & Export > Import Export > Export to a file > Comma separated values > choose what you want to export > choose a file name and location > done.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to export contacts to Excel from OWA? On the web mail, you can click Manage > Export Contacts

[image]

Check this article to see if it helpful to you: [Export contacts to a CSV file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-contacts-from-outlook-com-to-a-csv-file-578cca22-3550-4c73-b3f0-9978cfeac83f)